# Netezza and Regexp: how to remove all non letters from a string

Tags: regex, netezza

I'm having a bit of trouble with the syntax and the documentation only confuses me more.

I'm trying `regexp_extract_all(group_concat(score),'A-Z','')`, but getting this error:
ERROR [42S02] ERROR:  Function 'regexp_extract_all(varchar, unknown, unknown)' does not exist
    Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
    You may need to add explicit typecasts

I'm using a box that has the regexp functions installed.

Answer (score 3):

Got it:
`,sql_functions..regexp_replace(sql_functions..group_concat(score),'[0-9,]','')`

Apparently the regexp function is on another server named "sql_functions" and I needed to call it explicitly.

Comment: This actually indicates that the regexp functions (which are part of the functions collectively known as the SQL Extensions Toolkit) are installed in a database on the *same* system called SQL_FUNCTIONS.